# How to check if a variable is NOT equal to a string

Tags: python

I am trying to check is `osys` variable is not equal to `'Linux'`. The output of platform.system() on my machine is `'Linux'`. This then gets assigned to the variable of `osys`.

```
def getos():
osys=platform.system()
if osys is not "'Linux'":
    print(color.lightred + "This program only runs on Linux operating systems.")
    time.sleep(2)
    quit()
getos()
```

I am using this code to check if `osys` is `'Linux'`, and if not the program will close because the program only works on linux. Instead when I run this code I always get the output string of `This program only runs on Linux operating systems` instead of the code just continuing. Does anyone know how to fix this.

Comment: What about `if osys is not "Linux":`...? It's not clear why you've opted to include single quotes *inside* your string here. Voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: @esqew I think you meant `!= "Linux"`?

Comment: The `!=` operator should be used when comparing literals / strings, rather than `is`. This should raise a `SyntaxWarning`.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Right, thanks - moving too quickly this morning after my third cup of coffee. `if osys != "Linux":`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead you dont need quotes within the quotes.

```
if osys != "Linux":
```